# Average velocity and acceleration

Tags: kinematics, acceleration, vectors, velocity

I know to obtain the average of some vectors I compute the mean of the one dimensional components of each vector and constitute the average vector. My question is : why is this untrue for average velocity and acceleration? average velocity is computed as such only when it's one dimensional, whilst average acceleration isn't computed using this method at all، why is this?

Comment: It all depends on definition. E.g. for an object moving in circles at constant speed `v`, what do you want the average velocity to be? `(0,0,0)` or the scalar `v`? The per-component method gives you `(0,0,0)`.

Comment: So the average velocity and acceleration are only definitions and are not taken from a mathematical perspective of average?

Comment: I'm of course talking of an average that is used to analyse motion

Comment: Both versions of average velocity have their uses and are based on the mathematical concept and formulas of average. The vector average of `(0,0,0)` will tell you that the object mainly stays in the same place over a long-term observation. The scalar average `v` (first take the scalar momentary speeds, then their average) is useful e.g. if this is a car and you want to talk about fuel consumption.

Comment: As seen in @dzjur 's answer, "average velocity" is a shortened form of "time-weighted average of velocities".... but most treatments unfortunately don't emphasize the "time-weighted" part.

Answer (score 0):

Because time links into it, let me give an example:

We have chosen a coordinate system, and in this coordinate system, we have a mass that only has two velocities (easy), one of them is $v_1=(0,1)$ and the other one is $v_2=(1,0)$. Now what is the average velocity? Essentially it is where the point ended up, divided by the time it got there. But in order to find this out, you need to know how long either velocity was active.

So you need time, so just adding the two vectors together will not work. The average is now
$$v = \frac{v_1 \cdot t_1 + v_2 \cdot t_2}{t_1 + t_2}$$

Comment: It is unfortunate that textbook definitions of "average velocity" do not indicate that it is a "time-weighted average of velocities", as you show in your example. Most texts just write $\Delta \vec x/\Delta t$, but unfortunately leave out your calculation. In general, it is $\displaystyle \vec v_{avg}=\frac{\int \vec v\ dt}{\int dt}$.